# Google Drive API (python) - Can't retrieve Photos

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to write a python script that will retrieve all the Photos from my Google Drive.  I have created a service account and I am able to retrieve the sample pdf file "Getting Started" that is in my Google Drive account.  However I am not able to retrieve the *.jpg using the script.

Using the test api here and selecting phots,drive as the spaces parameter I get the expected results, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
scopes =['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(<service account file name>, scopes=scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
drive_service = build('drive','v3', http=http_auth)

page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(spaces='drive,photos',
                                      fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                      pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        print "No more photos"
        break;
```

Here is what I expect to get and this is what I get when I use the api test link:

```
{
"kind": "drive#fileList",
"incompleteSearch": false,
"files": [
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "0B0UYmRxQ5YMsc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl",
"name": "Getting started",
"mimeType": "application/pdf"
},
{
"kind": "drive#file",
"id": "1-b7wksGUCb825wNx7Ov-Si6EWaN6zSx11w",
"name": "IMG_180936.jpg",
"mimeType": "image/jpeg"
}
]
}
```

But this is what I get when i execute my code:

```
Found file: Getting started (0B7zoeZ330KvQc3RhcnRlcl9maWxl)
No more photos
```

No errors are produced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the `q="mimeType='image/jpeg'` in your code based in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters).

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='image/jpeg'",
                                          spaces='drive',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.  After investigating the issue further I found that the issue was with using a ServiceAccount and it not having access to photos added to Google Photo.  If I share the photos with the ServiceAccount I can successfully retrieve the information.

The API Explorer uses OAuth2 which has access to everything in the personal account.